# How can I handle incorrect user input into a scanner?

Tags: java

I am creating a class to use which handles user input. This is so that in other projects I can call methods from the class without having to worry about creating scanners in every new project.

There will be a separate method within the class to handle different variable types (float, int, String etc..). I have started with the float type:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Input {

public static float floatInput() {

    Scanner in1 = new Scanner(System.in);
    float in;

    if (in1.hasNextFloat()) {
        in = in1.nextFloat();
        return in;
    } else {
        System.out.print("Incorrect input type, try again");
        floatInput();
        return 0;
    }
}
```

This method works just fine, except that it must return a float in the else part. In this instance it is a zero, so when inputting to a calculator (for example), the zero causes any output to equal zero.

Is there a way of returning an 'empty' float value to overcome this problem?

Does anybody have any better suggestions for handling incorrect scanner input in general?

Thank you.

Comment: you probably wanted to return the `floatInput()` in the else branch, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just read your input as a `String` and check if it is a float value, else loop until it is or the user gets tired:

```
public static float floatInput() {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Input a float:");
    for(;;){
        try{
            return Float.parseFloat(scanner.next());
        } catch(NumberFormatException e){
            System.out.println("Incorrect input type, try again:");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static float floatInput() {

    Scanner in1 = new Scanner(System.in);
    float in = in1.nextFloat();

    while (/*in.isGood()*/) {
        System.out.println("Incorrect input type, try again:");
        in = in1.nextFloat();
    }

    return in;
}
```

This will prevent to call recursivelly while you still haveing instances of the method running on the background with open Scanners waiting for the return.

Also, you can be sure that the output will have nextFloat.

But you need to find a better way of checking if the float is correct such as a try catch block with a parse inside. hasNextFloat() won't tell you.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing as an 'empty' float. A float that has not been initialized defaults to 0.0f. If you were to return your 'in' variable, instead of just returning 0 in your else statement it would return 0.0.

Click [here](http://www.c4learn.com/java/java-default-values) to learn more about default values for primitive data types in Java.